# What happened to the thing that Will puked?

Tags: stranger-things

At the end of *Stranger Things* season 1, we can see Will puking up a slug in the bathroom. A year later, the events of the second season occur. In the second season, we can see D'art grow to become a demodog in weeks. That means the slug that Will vomited had more than enough time to become a fully grown demogorgon. But there weren't any fully grown demogorgons in the second season.

Comment: The slug grew up to become the demodog. It wasn't a demogorgon.

Comment: I heard it has its own spinoff series.  I might be wrong though.

Comment: @BrettFromLA *Stranger Things: The Slug Story* ?

Answer (score 9):

There are too many unknowns to answer that but there are a few possibilities. But first, we have to guess - are demogorgons and demodogs the same specie? It is quite probable that demodog is just an immature stage of the demogorgon (and the [Stranger Things Wiki](http://strangerthings.wikia.com/wiki/Demogorgon_(species)) seems to confirm this) - those two look quite similar, you could even say that demogorgon is bigger and bipedal demodog. There are many species that have such complicated life cycles with different stages looking very different to previous ones - for example [Phylloxera](https://ohiograpeweb.cfaes.ohio-state.edu/sites/grapeweb/files/imce/Nitika/Phylloxera%20life%20cycle.jpg) has 18!

If we'd assume that they are, then it is quite possible that D'art WAS the same slug that Will puked - it has stayed hidden slowly feeding (or even more possible - in hibernation waiting for signal) until it was big enough to process to the next stage.

If we assume that demodogs and demogorgons are not related, then either the slug that Will puked died, it is still hiding somewhere or it was just a demodog, not demogorgon slug.

Comment: The Wikia lists the demodog as the fifth stage in the lifecycle of the demogorgon.. the last,before full blown demogorgon.

Comment: @Gnemlock Does the wikia cite the creators of the show at all?  Cause there was no indication in season 2 that the dogs would become gorgons.  Without Word of God, that's only an assumption.

Comment: @Tim, It may have. I took a glance, and commented so others could look into it, if wanted. There was *a lot* of information, though. Several paragraphs per stage. It also had images from the show clearly showing each stage, and from the images alone, it was pretty obvious.